# Cannot read property firebase of undefined error

Tags: firebase, nativescript

I done what [the plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) said, but i am getting this error...

I am only calling firebase plugin like these:

`var firebasePlugin = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase")`

If I delete the line, there is no error.

Here is the virtual device screen.
[image]

Last logs
[image]

Comment: did u run  "tns run ios" or "tns run android" after adding plugin ?

Comment: @MarekMaszay of course Marek, I did run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tns run android
```

command solved my problem.

Thanks @MarekMaszay